# how to use conditionalpanel() in shiny r

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a shiny app where it allows you to select an input of what operation calculate. if the user chooses "Addition" it will show the two numeric input boxes (so they can input two numbers), if the user chooses "square" it will show only one numeric input box to square.

With this, I use `conditionalPanel` and if the condition is satisfied, it fetches through `uiOutput()` the `numericInput`s that I want. and same thing for square.

Now when I run this app, the conditional panels do not appear. Where did I go wrong? Thanks for checking out my question.

```
ui <- fluidPage( theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                 titlePanel("Basic Calculator"),
                 sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput("ops","Select what Operation use",choices = c("ADDITION","SQUARE")),
                   
                          helpText("Please input the appropriate number depending on the operations"),
                          conditionalPanel("input.ops=='ADDITION'", uiOutput("var2")),
                          conditionalPanel("input.ops=='SQUARE'", uiOutput("var1"))
                         
                          ),#sidebar panel
                  
                 
                   
)#fluidpage

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$basicmath <- renderText( ifelse(input$ops=="ADDITION",input$a+input$b,
                                  ifelse(input$ops=="SUBTRACTION",input$a-input$b,
                                  ifelse(input$ops=="SQUARE",input$a*input$a,
                                  ifelse(input$ops=="SQUARE ROOT",sqrt(input$a),
                                  ifelse(input$ops=="MULTIPLICATION",input$a*input$b,"not a valid operation"))))),
   
  output$var2 <- renderUI({
                            helpText("this will show to input two numerics to be added")
    
                          }) ,
  
  output$var1 <- renderUI({
                           helpText("this will show to input one numeric to square")
    
  })                             
      
)}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The key issue you were having is that you put the `uiOutputs` inside the calculation output that you anticipated. It is better to separate them, since the calculation output won't run until it has the necessary prerequisite values (your input values). In addition, because you hadn't specified an output location for `basicmath`, the app didn't know where to put anything inside that call to `renderText()`. Below is working code that gets the right UI elements to appear.

One other thing you were missing in your `renderUI` was the use of `tagList()`. This helps ensure that all of your elements are packaged together, not just the last one.

Note that the math part does not work, but it looks like that was just a placeholder. When you do start to use it, be sure to use unique ids for each input. You have several instances of `input$a` and `input$b`, which probably isn't a workable approach.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- fluidPage( theme = shinytheme("slate"),
                 titlePanel("Basic Calculator"),
                 sidebarPanel(
                   selectInput("ops","Select what Operation use",choices = c("ADDITION","SQUARE")),
                   helpText("Please input the appropriate number depending on the operations"),
                   conditionalPanel("input.ops=='ADDITION'", uiOutput("var2")),
                   conditionalPanel("input.ops=='SQUARE'", uiOutput("var1"))
                 ),
                 mainPanel(
                   textOutput("basicmath")
                 )
)#fluidpage

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$var2 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      helpText("this will show to input two numerics to be added"),
      splitLayout(
        numericInput("var2a", label = "Input one number", value = NULL),
        numericInput("var2b", label = "Input another number", value = NULL)
      )
    )
  })
  
  output$var1 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      helpText("this will show to input one numeric to square"),
      numericInput("var1a", label = "Input a number", value = NULL)
    )
  })
  
  output$basicmath <- renderText( {ifelse(input$ops=="ADDITION",input$a+input$b,
                                         ifelse(input$ops=="SUBTRACTION",input$a-input$b,
                                                ifelse(input$ops=="SQUARE",input$a*input$a,
                                                       ifelse(input$ops=="SQUARE ROOT",sqrt(input$a),
                                                              ifelse(input$ops=="MULTIPLICATION",input$a*input$b,"not a valid operation")))))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I ran it and it worked!  Im going to add the remaining conditionals and operations now. THis is really helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't forget to accept the answer to indicate to others that it solved the problem.